# Countdown timer doesn't render right on Chrome/Safari, but OK on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, browser

```
function countDownRound() {
    if(myRoundTimeRemaining >= 0){
        var secs = myRoundTimeRemaining;
        if(secs < 10)
        {
            secs = "0" + secs;
        }
        $("#countdown").html(':'+secs);
        CountdownTimer = setTimeout(countDownRound, 1000);
        myRoundTimeRemaining--;
    }
    else{
        $("#countdown").html('');
    }
}
```

The code above does what's expected, on Firefox. Every second a decreasing number is displayed in the "countdown" element.

On Safari and Chrome, the code runs properly, but the on-screen element does not change.  If something else happens (such as resizing the browser window) the elements update properly while.

This looks like some kind of optimization or thread-based problem, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: works fine for me on chrome http://jsfiddle.net/br4uK/

Comment: Works fine for me too. What version of Chrome and Safari are you using?

Comment: Interesting. It might have something do do with JQuery's animation stack - I found this warning: "Because of the nature of requestAnimationFrame(), you should never queue animations using a setInterval or setTimeout loop." Though this object isn't animating, some of our other objects are...

Comment: Looks like the new browsers are very aggressive about focus and updating.

Comment: Why are you using a recursive function? I think that with setInterval the code would be cleaner, and easier on the 'thread side of things'

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me too on Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Perhaps in this case that you don`t need to use html tags to display your result, **text()** may work better than **html()**.

Try using

```
$("#countdown").text(':'+secs);
```

instead html().

OBS: Seems that some kids of instability on your operacional system can also affects browser rendering. Could someone please confirm or deny this?